# Google Chrome crashing after file upload

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, crash

I have been experiencing this issue for over a month now on `22.04`. To make sure that things are ok, I downloaded a new `.deb`, uninstalled the old one and reinstalled `Google Chrome`.

But whenever I upload something, Google Chrome will freeze. It only goes away if I use `System Monitor` to kill the crashpad in the listing.

Not just Google Chrome, I am facing an identical issue with `Vivaldi` as well. But `Firefox`, which exists in the same machine works without any issues. I think Vivaldi is based on Chromium and hence the issue.

Also, the file uploads are successful when I check later.

I have dual boot Windows 10 where everything works fine. Any help will be great.

Edit 1:

From var/log/syslog

> vivaldi-stable.desktop[10410]:
> [10405:10405:1219/041714.220540:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in
> promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by
> returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was
> received", source:
> chrome-extension://mpognobbkildjkofajifpdfhcoklimli/browser.html (0)

Edit 2:

[image]

Edit 3:

Looks like the JS blocking extension in Opera was the root cause. Now Vivaldi is responding properly. But I am still having issues adding attachments to Gmail in Google Chrome

> app-gnome-google\x2dchrome-6344.scope: Consumed 47.400s CPU time.
>
> gnome-shell[2618]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this.actor is
> null#012_syncEnabled@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:138:25#012onStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:150:35#012_makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:151:22#012_easeActorProperty/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:317:60#012_destroyWindowDone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1596:21#012onStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1564:39#012_makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:151:22#012_easeActor/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:240:64

Edit 4:

The issue persists in full form. The latest from var/log/syslog for chrome after uninstalling Opera.

google-chrome.desktop[10107]: [10101:10135:1221/123702.460602:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser”

Edit 5:

I uninstalled Opera and uninstalled all extensions from Chrome and Vivaldi. The issue persists though.

> google-chrome.desktop[9034]:
> [9028:9061:1222/122107.972925:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to
> call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path=
> /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop:
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface
> “org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser”
>
> google-chrome.desktop[9034]:
> [9028:9061:1222/122107.973502:ERROR:select_file_dialog_linux_portal.cc(274)]
> Failed to read portal version property google-chrome.desktop[9034]:
> [9072:9072:1222/122108.366031:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to
> export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
> google-chrome.desktop[9034]:
> [9072:9072:1222/122108.366130:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to
> export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
> google-chrome.desktop[9034]:
> [9072:9072:1222/122108.366183:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to
> export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
>
> google-chrome.desktop[9034]:
> [9028:9028:1222/122111.981403:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(694)]
> Message 1 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost
>
> google-chrome.desktop[9034]:
> [9028:9028:1222/122111.981429:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(694)]
> Message 1 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost Dec 22 12:21:17
> njan-ente dbus-daemon[975]: [system] Activating via systemd: service
> name='org.freedesktop.hostname1'
> unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.187'
> (uid=1000 pid=9028 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome "
> label="unconfined") Starting Hostname Service... dbus-daemon[975]:
> [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
> systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22wfA.png): Started Hostname Service. systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22wfA.png):
> systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully. systemd[2412]:
> app-gnome-google\x2dchrome-9028.scope: Consumed 18.680s CPU time.

Edit 6, info requested by +starkus

```
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP

ubuntu:GNOME

$ /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal -v

XDP: load portals from /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals
XDP: loading /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals/gnome-shell.portal
XDP: portal implementation for gnome
XDP: portal implementation supports org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Access
XDP: loading /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals/gnome-keyring.portal
XDP: portal implementation for gnome
XDP: portal implementation supports org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Secret
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.MemoryMonitor
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.PowerProfileMonitor
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.NetworkMonitor
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.ProxyResolver
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.Trash
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.GameMode
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.Realtime

** (/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal:13226): WARNING **: 13:03:35.xxx: No skeleton to export
XDP: Using gnome-shell.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Access in GNOME
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.Device
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.WebExtensions
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.Location
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.Camera
XDP: Using gnome-keyring.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Secret in GNOME
XDP: providing portal org.freedesktop.portal.Secret
```

Edit 7:

```
$ apt list --installed "*desktop-portal*" | cut -d/ -f1

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Listing...
xdg-desktop-portal
```

Comment: Is there anything written to `/var/log/syslog` that might explain the issue? These things usually leave some sort of hint behind unless the I/O subsystem is completely saturated 

Comment: @matigo  it has some reference to an extension. I am not sure which. Please see the edited post.

Comment: I removed all extensions from Chrome, Vivaldi and Chromium. And, shutdown and again started the computer. But sadly, Vivaldi crashes when I download a file as well. I forgot to mention that not only upload, and downloading attachments are also causing this issue from the beginning. In the error log, I still see some (the same) extension causing the trouble. Is it some malware? I have Opera, is it Chromium based? I have a few extensions in that well.

Comment: JS block extension in Opera was having some issue. I removed that. But Google Chrome Gmail attachment is still freezing. :(

Comment: What does `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` in a terminal tell you? And `/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal -v`?

Comment: @starkus added it as an edit in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: `implementation supports org.freedesktop.impl.portal.FileChooser` is missing. What's the output of `apt list --installed "*desktop-portal*" | cut -d/ -f1`?

Comment: @starkus it says `xdg-desktop-portal` , full info updated in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: I'd give it a try with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-tests xdg-desktop-portal`. Also if you have some flatpak apps installed I'd give `flatpak repair && flatpak uninstall --unused` a try. While `xdg-desktop-portal-tests` is not really necessary but you can give it a try.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it maybe would be better to run `sudo apt update && flatpak update` before.

Comment: Thanks. I have not installed Flatpak yet. I will try the other option.

Comment: It is working fine now @starkus , thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Hi, If you can post it as an answer, I can approve it and add bounty points to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `implementation supports org.freedesktop.impl.portal.FileChooser` is missing in `/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal`.

It is provided by `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` Also `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` does provide a GTK+/GNOME implementation for the desktop-agnostic xdg-desktop-portal service.

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` but I would also reinstall `xdg-desktop-portal` to make sure all dependencies will get updated. Because of the listed installed snaps shown in your post you could install `xdg-desktop-portal-tests` as well.
Just open a terminal and run:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-tests xdg-desktop-portal`

Good luck,

Comment: I think you missed a small part  of the command which you shared through the comment : `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-tests xdg-desktop-portal`

Comment: Thank you. edited.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the [Chromium snap](https://snapcraft.io/chromium), this installs alongside any other Chrome / Chromium that you have, there is no need to remove them.

For me it has been working fine on 22.04 and also 22.10.